# Plotting line across international dateline with Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to plot global storm tracks, but when the storms cross the dateline (and longitudes go from ~360 to ~0), the line loops all the way around the plotting space.
[Here's what the plot looks like. See the weird straight lines near the top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L45C0.png)
Here's my code:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson())
ax.set_global()

ax.coastlines()

for i in range(nstorms-1): #loop through each TC
        bidx = start_idx[i]
        eidx = start_idx[i+1]
        plt.plot(clons[bidx:eidx],clats[bidx:eidx],transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

If I try changing the transform to Geodetic, it looks like this: [image: this is what happens]

Comment: Hey Alyssa, is there a minimal reproducible example you can provide? I.e. that includes the storm track data for just one of the storms that demonstrate this issue?

Comment: Sure:
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()
lons = [347.87, 349.62, 352.4414, 358.06, 3.69, 7.20]
lats = [32.33, 33.63, 34.8, 37.14, 39.25, 42.30]
plt.plot(lons,lats,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot polylines that cross the dateline, you need to sanitize the longitudes properly. For example, values 359 to 2 should be adjusted to 359 to 362. In the demo code below, `sanitize_lonlist()` is used to sanitize a list of longitude values before using it to plot a red zigzag line.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sanitize_lonlist(lons):
    new_list = []
    oldval = 0
    treshold = 10  # used to compare adjacent longitudes
    for ix,ea in enumerate(lons):
        diff = oldval - ea
        if (ix>0):
            if (diff>treshold):
                ea = ea+360
        oldval = ea
        new_list.append(ea)
    return new_list

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Robinson()) 
ax.set_global() 
ax.coastlines(alpha=0.3)

# sample long/lat data for demo purposes
# xdateline: list of longitudes that cross dateline several times
xdateline = [347,349,352,358,4,7,8,3,359,358,360,3,5,359,1,357,0,8,12,6,357,349]
# ydateline: list of accompanying latitudes
ydateline = range(len(xdateline))

# plot the line crossing dateline using `sanitized` values of longitudes
plt.plot(sanitize_lonlist(xdateline), ydateline, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color='red') 

plt.show()
```

[image: datelinexing]

Using the raw values of `xdateline` to plot with the line of code:-

```
plt.plot(xdateline, ydateline, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color='red')
```

the plot will be:-

[image: bad-plot]

Comment: I have implemented this approach and it works, thank you!

Comment: @AlyssaStansfield Since you are new user, you don't have enough reputation to upvote or comment in general. This is your chance to gain some reputation points by marking this as `accepted` answer -- it also the correct way to thank.

Comment: @AlyssaStansfield If you edit your question by adding the content with the (updated) working code that can be used by anyone as I did, people (and me) will happily upvote your question as it is useful to them.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this github issue](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/368), this is expected behaviour since `PlateCarree` is a projected coordinate system.

> The PlateCarree coordinate system is Cartesian where a line between two points is straight (in that coordinate system). The Cartesian system has no knowledge of datelines/antimeridians and so when you ask for a line between -170 and +170 you get a line of length 340. It can never be the case that the PlateCarree projection interprets these numbers and chooses to draw a non-cartesian line

One solution is to use the Geodetic transform in your plot calls:

```
plt.plot(clons[bidx:eidx], clats[bidx:eidx], transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
```

Or modify your data to make more sense when using the `PlateCarree` system, e.g. by identifying where values loop from 360-> 0 and adding 360 to all values after that occurs. You could shift them onto a different range (e.g. -180..180) but you'll have the same issue with data crossing +/- 180 as you do with 0/360 currently.

Comment: If I just change the transform to Geodetic, it doesn't work (see my edit above). I will try shifting the values by 360 when they go from 360 -> 0.